# How do I upgrade to ubuntu 23.04 without dataloss

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, update-manager

i am currently using ubuntu 22.04 LTS and i want to upgrade to latest version. I know that i have to upgrade first to 22.10 and then to ubuntu 23.04. but i am worried about my data.Is it safe to upgrade to the latest version without dataloss?

Comment: Whatever you are doing on your computer your data is at risk unless you have a backup. Upgrading is a process where there can be increased risk to data but you should always have backups if you value your data. Make sure you are fully upgraded in 22.04 before proceeding to 22.10. Check again before upgrading to 23.04. It’s also good to check that you have plenty of disk space available before starting. 5GB should be enough

Comment: I'd recommend reading the release notes for what matters to you, you've tagged Xubuntu so I'd read those notes, and also the Ubuntu release notes as they cover different parts of your system (why links to Ubuntu release notes are provided at https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/22.10/upgrading). We perform QA-test upgrades and what we discover during testing (*where helpful & couldn't be resolved*) goes into those notes!  Key is backup first; you can re-install Xubuntu anyway without data loss (*if done correctly without format too; it's my fallback if I have issues or just lack time*)

Comment: Just a further comment to @PonJar's comment; I wouldn't start a *release-upgrade* with 5GB of space remaining... I know my systems well enough & the apps I have installed; and I'd ensure I have 8GB free before starting; and do a quick app check to ensure it's not going to get close.. On systems where I don't have space; I usually opt for the *upgrade via re-install* (*non-destructive re-install mentioned last comment*) as that erases system directories & re-installs, then downloads *manually installed* apps to install; needing less space than download of everything, install of everything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: I recommend inexperienced users stay on the LTS versions if no urgent problem forces the upgrade.